# How to increase the time capturing video using Open CV

Tags: javascript, java, python, arrays, python-3.x

This is output Error shows that it cannot unpacked non-iterable numpy.float 64 object

```js
[Command: python -u C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\finding-lanes\lane.py]
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:380: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  avg = a.mean(axis)
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:170: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\finding-lanes\lane.py", line 76, in <module>
    frame = process(frame)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\finding-lanes\lane.py", line 68, in process
    averaged_lines = average_slope_intercept(frame, lines)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\finding-lanes\lane.py", line 26, in average_slope_intercept
    left_line = make_coordinates(image, left_fit_average) # Specify coordinates of image and slope and intercept of left line
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\finding-lanes\lane.py", line 5, in make_coordinates
    slope, intercept = line_parameters
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float64 object
[Finished in 14.483s]
```

Comment: Can you post a code snippet on what you are doing at the moment?

Comment: Hi Ognjen. Im kind of new to programming. Can you show me how to post a code snippet onto the site

Comment: You can edit your post and there is a {} symbol in your toolbar - a code snippet. :)

Comment: Hi Ognjen i already show the code just let me know if they sth i need to change to increase the time capturing Video to detect lanes. Thanks

Comment: The total time duration for the video is 25 sec. The problem is when i try to detect the lanes in a video the code is working but it only detect for 10 sec then the frame drop.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the video length to be fair - it's quite possible you're getting an error/exception at a frame that is at the 10th second or so - that your code just crashes. Could you check and post the program output as well? The exit code, and similar?

Comment: Hi Ognjen I already show the exit code. It shows the type of error as it cannot unpacked non-interable numpy.float64 object. What does it means?

Comment: Can't really go into details of it, but try reading if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54273077/cannot-unpack-non-iterable-numpy-float64-object-python3-opencv helps.

Also, you should return your code & question, you just edited the post and pasted the output over everything..