# cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float64 object : Keras dataset in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I've got this error and haven't been knowing how to solve it.

I got this error in this sentence.

```
[Loss, Accuracy] = model.evaluate(x_test, y_train)
```

Here is my full code.
I was trying binary classification with IMDB(Internet Movie DataBase) in dataset of keras API.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam

# Getting Data from imdb
# train_data includes 25000 reviews for movie.
# one element of train_data is list with integer elements, and each integer element is mapped to a certain word
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import imdb
(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)

# Considering 10000 frequently used words
# Making the number of input feature to 10000
# Each unit of input layer means a certain word, and it has 1 when the word is included in a input sentence
def vectorize_sequence(sequences,dimension=10000):
    results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))
    for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
        results[i,sequence] = 1
    return results

x_train = vectorize_sequence(train_data)
x_test = vectorize_sequence(test_data)

y_train = train_labels
y_test = test_labels

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(10000,), activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=1e-2), loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000)
[Loss, Accuracy] = model.evaluate(x_test, y_train)   # I got the error in here
```

And here is specific error message that I got after running above thing in the jupyter notebook.

```
25000/25000 [==============================] - 1s 50us/sample - loss: 2.6755
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-4d3cda640a6a> in <module>
----> 1 [Loss, Accuracy] = model.evaluate(x_test, y_train)

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float64 object
```

How should I solve this? And what should I be careful to prevent that error?

Comment: I think this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54273077/cannot-unpack-non-iterable-numpy-float64-object-python3-opencv) should answer your question. There might be cases when the `evaluate` function might not be returning a correct value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float64 object python3 opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54273077/cannot-unpack-non-iterable-numpy-float64-object-python3-opencv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `return_dict=True` to the `model.evaluate()` to see what you have, most probably you don't have any metrics. Like this:

```
res_dict = model.evaluate(x_test, y_train, return_dict=True)
```

See the documentation of the evaluate function: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model

> return_dict
>
> If True, loss and metric results are returned as a dict, with each key
> being the name of the metric. If False, they are returned as a list.

To add metric to your model you need to provide a list to the `compile` function as `metrics` parameter:

example:

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.01),
          loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
          metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])
```

see: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Metric

You most probably need a `tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()` metric.