# Facemask Recognition using TFlite in Raspberry Pi 3B+ with Python3

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, raspberry-pi

I try to use TFlite for my facemask recognition project. But the problem is it has errors. The problem can Stream. However, if it detects a human face/facemask the error will terminate the system.

Here's the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/fm_detection/fm_tflite.py", line 113, in <module>
    (mask, withoutMask) = pred
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float32 object
```

Here's my coding

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from gpiozero import LED, Buzzer
import numpy as np
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import os
import sys

led = LED(19)
buzzer = Buzzer(26)

def detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, interpreter):
    
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (224, 224),
        (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))

    
    faceNet.setInput(blob)
    detections = faceNet.forward()
    print(detections.shape)

    
    faces = []
    locs = []
    preds = []

    
    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
        
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

        
        if confidence > 0.5:
            
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

            
            (startX, startY) = (max(0, startX), max(0, startY))
            (endX, endY) = (min(w - 1, endX), min(h - 1, endY))

            
            face = frame[startY:endY, startX:endX]
            face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            face = cv2.resize(face, (224, 224))
            face = img_to_array(face)
            face = preprocess_input(face)

            
            faces.append(face)
            locs.append((startX, startY, endX, endY))

    
    if len(faces) > 0:
        
        faces = np.array(faces, dtype="float32")
        #preds = maskNet.predict(faces, batch_size=32)
        interpreter.allocate_tensors()
        interpreter.set_tensor(interpreter.get_input_details()[0]["index"], faces)
        interpreter.invoke()
        preds = interpreter.tensor(interpreter.get_output_details()[0]["index"])()[0]

    
    return (locs, preds)

# load our serialized facemask model from disk
prototxtPath = "/home/pi/Desktop/fm_detection/face_detector/deploy.prototxt"
weightsPath = "/home/pi/Desktop/fm_detection/face_detector/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"
faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)


#maskNet = load_model("facemask_model.model")
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter("facemask_model.tflite")

# initialize the video stream
print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = VideoStream(src=1).start()


# loop over the frames
while True:

    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)

    
    (locs, preds) = detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, interpreter)

    
    for (box, pred) in zip(locs, preds):
        # unpack the bounding box and predictions
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box
        (mask, withoutMask) = pred

        
        label = "Mask" if mask > withoutMask else "No Mask"
        color = (0, 255, 0) if label == "Mask" else (0, 0, 255)
        led.on() if mask > withoutMask else led.off()
        buzzer.beep(0.1, 0.1, 1) if mask > withoutMask else led.off()
        
        time.sleep(2)
        led.off() if mask > withoutMask else led.off()
        os.system("espeak -s 130 'THANK YOU'") if mask > withoutMask else led.off()
        sys.exit() if sw2Press else buzzer.off()

        
        cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, startY - 10),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, color, 2)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), color, 2)

    
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    
    if key == ord("q"):
        break


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

The program will be stuck at the moment it detects the human face. Hope someone can help me.
Thank You

Comment: As the error suggests: Problem is the line `(mask, withoutMask) = pred`. `pred` is a float and you try to unpack it into two variables.

Comment: So, I need to modify the pred type from float to int? How to do it Sir?

Comment: I don't think that will help. `pred` is one value and your code tries to unpack  that value to two variables thus the error. You need to at least two values so that you can assign one to each (e.g., `(one, two) = ['1', '2']`).   So you need to check what is in `preds` or use `pred`as either `masked`and create `unmasked` or vice versa.

Comment: Hi! Did you check these issues with same Error stack trace.                   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54273077/cannot-unpack-non-iterable-numpy-float64-object-python3-opencv                                                               https://www.py4u.net/discuss/260154